# send command to every running instance of urxvt

Tags: terminal

i'm trying to write a script that would change the color scheme of all running terminals (im using urxvt). the idea is to have a keyboard shortcut to switch between light and dark solarized themes.
so far I tried dynamic-colors script https://github.com/sos4nt/dynamic-colors and it works as expected, I can change between light and dark solarized colors of the running terminal. 
I was thinking that maybe I could execute this command in every running instance of urxvt, but have no idea how to acomplish that. 
also please share any suggestions how I could tackle my main problem (creating a script that would change the colorscheme of all running terminals).

Comment: Did you ever find a nice solution?

Answer (score 2):

currently i'm using dynamic-colors script https://github.com/sos4nt/dynamic-colors
and this bit of python code changes all terminals to light or dark (version)

```
pts = os.listdir('/dev/pts/')
for each_pts in pts:
     if is_number(each_pts):
         subprocess.call('echo "`.dynamic-colors/bin/dynamic-colors switch solarized-{0}`" > /dev/pts/{1}'.format(version,each_pts), shell=True)
```

Comment: It didn't notify me on your answer. I found a different solution, using termite which is capable of reloading it's configuration, and i managed to have vim update it's colors to globally! Great success. Oh, your solution makes a lot of sense, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Just tried to use this solution, as i wanted to source my zsh file in all running terminals. I tried with urxvt and dynamic-colors to see it working, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is anything missing? I've imported OS and changed .dynamic.....solarized, to my version (which works when run in a terminal). Any ideas?

Comment: i really don't know why it may not work for you. are you sure the color config names of dynamic colors match the ones that are called in the script? in my script version variable is "dark" or "light" and configs are called solarized-light, solarized dark.

Comment: can you share your solution to changing vim colors? that's the part missing from my 'auto color switching' script. also I don't know how to change the theme of a running firefox instance.

Comment: Yes, if i write the command directly in the terminal it changes color. Wierd.
Yeah i haven't managed to fix firefox either. I have <Space>t in firefox (Pentadactyl) setup to change both the firefox theme (tab bar) and the pentadactyl theme. I upgraded to Neovim earlier today, which made is rather simple actually. A solution not unlike your own. A python script attaching to the running neovim windows and setting background=light/dark. (which updates solarized).

Comment: Forgive me for the way it is formatted, not much power in these comment boxes. from neovim import attach, nvim_instances=glob.glob("/tmp/nvim*"), for instance in nvim_instances: nvim = attach('socket', path=instance+'/0'), nvim.command('set background='+sys.argv[1]), sys.argv being either light or dark as input to the script.

Comment: ok, thanks, tried that, works ok with neovim, but still I'm not sure if I want to switch, I'm afraid some things from my customized spf-13 configs may not work, I have to check that.

Answer (score 1):

To change colors for all open terminals, put this script in a directory to your liking:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$(dirname $0)

# get terminals opened by user
TERMINALS=($(ls -l /dev/pts/* | grep $USER | awk '{print $10}'))

if [[ -e "$DIR"/themes/"$1".sh ]]; then
  source "$DIR"/themes/"$1".sh

  MAX=`echo ${#TERMINALS[@]} - 1 | bc`
  for i in $(seq 0 $MAX); do
    printf "\033]10;$foreground\007" > ${TERMINALS[$i]}
    printf "\033]11;[$opacity]$background\007" > ${TERMINALS[$i]}
    printf "\033]12;$cursor\007" > ${TERMINALS[$i]}
    printf "\033]17;$highlight_bg\007" > ${TERMINALS[$i]}
    printf "\033]19;$highlight_fg\007" > ${TERMINALS[$i]}
    printf "\033]708;$border\007" > ${TERMINALS[$i]}
    for j in $(seq 0 15); do
      printf "\033]4;$j;${colors[j]}\007" > ${TERMINALS[$i]}
    done
  done
else
  echo "No theme named "$1" available!"
fi
```

Create a subdirectory called »themes«, e. g. /path/to/colorScript/themes, and create color themes by adjusting the following template to your favorite colors:

```
opacity=100
foreground="#272727"
background="#F0DCC9"
cursor="#2B2B2B"
mouse_foreground=""
highlight_bg=""
highlight_fg="" # works only if highlight_bg is set
border=""

# defining color0, …, color15
colors=(
"#000000"
"#CC2929"
"#29CC29"
"#A64934"
"#2929CC"
"#0D5F2B"
"#566F28"
"#ffffff"
"#ffff00"
"#C12D38"
"#7F2E2E"
"#ED0C11"
"#C0471B"
"#990000"
"#778087"
"#ffffff"
)
```

Save those templates as shell scripts (*.sh). The line

```
source "$DIR"/themes/"$1".sh
```

in the first code box of my post will import all variables defined in the color script and use them afterwards.

Execute the script for changing the terminal colors by typing

```
bash /path/to/colorScript/scriptName.sh "Name of your theme"
```

where "Name of your theme" is the exact name of the color theme in your ./themes subdirectory (without the *.sh extension).

If you want to invoke a terminal with one of your color themes instead of the default values defined in ~/.Xresources or ~/.Xdefaults, you just type:

```
urxvt -e bash -c 'bash /path/to/colorScript/change.sh "Name of your theme" && bash'
```

The line above can, of course, be used for launchers, as well. Putting the »&& bash« at the end of this line prevents the new terminal window from closing immediately and will make it respond to your input.